# How to read event viewer log in Windows XP in C#.net

Tags: c#, event-viewer

I'm using the below XML Query to read system "Turn on event" from event viewer in last 24 hours.

```
string query = "<QueryList>" +
                "<Query Id=\"0\" Path=\"System\">" +
                "<Select Path=\"System\">*[System[(EventID=6005) and TimeCreated[timediff(@SystemTime) &lt;= 86400000]]]</Select>" +
                "</Query>" +
                "</QueryList>";
```

It works well on Windows 7 and above but on Windows XP, I'm getting the below error:

> Error:Operation is not supported on this platform

Can someone please help in reading the Turn On event in Windows XP from event viewer in C#.net?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Filtering by `XPpath` was introduced first with `Vista`. For `XP` you would have to use another implementation using [`EventLog` class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/74e2ybbs(v=vs.110).aspx).

[Example:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2633466/reading-eventlog-c-sharp-errors)

```
EventLog aLog = new EventLog();
aLog.Log = "Application";
aLog.MachineName = ".";  // Local machine

string message = "\'Service started\'";

foreach (EventLogEntry entry in aLog.Entries)
{
    if (entry.Source.Equals("tvNZB")
     && entry.EntryType == EventLogEntryType.Information)
    {
        if (entry.Message.EndsWith(message))
        {
            //write it somewhere
        }
    }
}
```